Unexpected sbrk() syscall behavior
I faced unexpected sbrk behavior, I was expecting it to return previous break value on successful calls, so I made my functions to be like:

void* get_current_break_value(void){
    void* current_break_value = sbrk(0);
    if (current_break_value == (void*) -1){
        return NULL;
    }
    return current_break_value;
    
}
void* get_more_raw_memory(uint32_t size){ 
    void* res = sbrk(size);
    if (res == (void*) -1){
        return NULL;
    }
    return res;
}
    
int main(int argc,char** argv){
    void *cbv, *pbv;
    pbv=get_current_break_value();
    printf("previous break value:\t%p\n",pbv);
    
    cbv=get_more_raw_memory(5);
    printf("current break value:\t%p\n",cbv);
    
    

    return 0;
}


here where the unexpected behavior was observed:
gcc mem.c -o mem; ./mem
previous break value:   0x5649c2c39000
current break value:    0x5649c2c5a000


what I was expecting is:
1- previous break value to be equal to current break value
2- to move break value by multiple of page size, wich is 4096
then I tried this:

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    void *cbv;
    cbv=get_current_break_value();
    printf("previous break value:\t%p\n",cbv);
    
    cbv=get_current_break_value();
    printf("previous break value:\t%p\n",cbv);
    
    
    return 0;
}

and the result was:
gcc mem.c -o mem; ./mem
previous break value:   0x5603cf854000
previous break value:   0x5603cf875000

the funny thing is when I tried to print a string before i tried to use sbrk this is the result correct
    
int main(int argc,char** argv){
    void *cbv;
    printf("123456789\n");
    cbv=get_current_break_value();
    printf("previous break value:\t%p\n",cbv);
    
    cbv=get_more_raw_memory(55);
    printf("previous break value:\t%p\n",cbv);
    
    
    cbv=get_more_raw_memory(55);
    printf("previous break value:\t%p\n",cbv);
    
    return 0;
}

output:
gcc mem.c -o mem; ./mem
123456789
previous break value:   0x56144e4d7000
previous break value:   0x56144e4d7000
previous break value:   0x56144e4d7037


so I have some questions
1- what printf has to do with this?
2- how to make sure sbrk behave as documented?
3- why sbrk does not move the break value by multiple of page size?

The first time you call printf, it allocates memory for its own use. (This may differ in various implementations of printf and may depend on the format string you pass it.)
